# Login crypting system PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, encryption

I'm creating a website in **PHP 5.3** and MySQL. I need a tip. What's the best crypt and decrypt system today? I know that Sha1 and MD5 was hacked... And, i f anyone know a secure system, can help me with a example to use that?
Thanks!

Comment: MD5 wasn't hacked. It still can't be 'un-encrypted' in traditional ways, however there are large databases on MD5 encrypted strings which are used for hash comparisons. Also, MD5 was never really intended to be a password encryption function. Its a way to check the validity of a file or string, or other peice of data

Comment: Regardless of the hashing algorithm, you should use a salt.

Comment: @PhilCross http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2011/08/rainbow-table-is-dead.html

Comment: You want to check out **bcrypt**. See for example http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/16209/php-login-authentication-with-bcrypt . It's not so much the hash you use, as the *way* you use it. Google for 'best practices with password hashing' - you may want to strengthen cookie handling too.

Comment: @PeeHaa As pointed out in the comments, that blog post completely misunderstands the nature of rainbow tables and how they relate to brute force attacks.

Comment: @francesco-guardiani I just posted an answer that I've been working on that includes some code examples of salting passwords

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Encrypting" and "decrypting" is not the same as *hashing*, which is what you're really after! PHP 5.5 will provide a good, simple API for a strong password hashing algorithm using bcrypt, one of the strongest accepted algorithms to date for this purpose. [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/) enables this API today in current PHP versions in a forward-compatible implementation.

Comment: I'm trying with bcrypt with cript() function but is one way. With this i can crypt but i can't decrypt correct?

Comment: Because hashing is a one way operation which is not reversible. And that's exactly what you want when storing passwords; you *do not want* the responsibility of storing actual passwords!

Comment: @deceze I posted a way to implement a basic salting algorithm

Comment: @Charles OK. Note that a bcrypt based hash (which includes a salt) is vastly preferable to an unstretched SHA1 hash though. SHA1 is too *fast* to withstand serious brute force attacks.

Answer (score 1):

For a simple hashing algorithm, take a look at the [SHA-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) family of hashing algorithms. These algorithms have no successful published attacks, and when you use a salt (that is an extra bit of data combined with your password, then hashed) you will create a very secure password storage system.

> What's the best crypt and decrypt system today?

You've listed hashing algorithms, which are one way. That is, they can not be decrypted. If you want to use a good algorithm for encrypting and decrypting values, then look at the [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard). With a 256 bit key size, this is the current standard for encryption and security.

Comment: Outright attacks are less an issue these days than the ability to calculate rainbow tables of known hashes to find passwords by brute force.

Comment: @Chris I posted an example that details how to salt the password

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you've heard that they have been 'hacked' is because rainbow tables have become a viable and popular way to 'crack' encrypted passwords (that haven't been salted).  If you'd like more information about this, a quick google search for *MD5 Rainbow Table* or a related search for another encryption algorithm will provide many useful links with information.

The most secure way to store passwords would be to use a salt in addition to encrypting a password with a one-way encryption algorithm such as MD5, SHA1, etc.  These are the steps you take to implement a salted password system:

*Note: These are just a few example methods that show you how to salt the password using a random salt.  For brevity I have left out the encryption.  If you don't know how to encrypt a string using the sha1(), md5(), or related functions then this will not help you much.*

### Safely Storing (salted) Encrypted Passwords In Database

**What you will need:**

- PHP (5.3+ preferably!)
- SQL Database (e.g. MySQL, MariaDB, PostgreSQL, Oracle, DB2, etc)
- Ability to insert/retrieve rows from a SQL database from PHP (mysqli, PDO, etc)
- Ability to use basic encryption algorithm functions in PHP (e.g. sha1(), md5(), etc)

### 1. Create Your User Database & Write Query:

*Note: user_pass is 40 characters long because this tutorial uses SHA1, this number will change with the encryption algorithm*

```
CREATE TABLE userbase (
  user_id    int(10)    NOT NULL    UNSIGNED    AUTO_INCREMENT    PRIMARY KEY,
  user_name    varchar(18)    NOT NULL    UNIQUE KEY,  
  user_pass    char(40)    CHARACTER SET utf8    COLLATE ut8_bin    NOT NULL.
  user_salt    char(10)    NOT NULL    UNIQUE KEY,
  user_email    varchar(70)    NOT NULL    UNIQUE KEY
) ENGINE=innodb,CHARACTER SET=utf8, COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
```

---

**QUERY:**

```
INSERT INTO `userbase`(`user_name`, `user_pass`, 
                       `user_salt`, `user_email`)
VALUES(:name, :pass, :salt, :email);
```

### 2. Write Registration Script

```
public function getSalt()
  // password should have already been validated
{
    // retrieve random number within character index of SHA1 salt:
    $i = mt_rand(1, 28);
    // retrieve current unix time in seconds since midnight Jan 1, 1970:
    $unixTime = time();
    // take 10char substring of the SHA1 hash of $unixTime from random index:
    return ($salt = substr(sha1($unixTime), $i, 10));
}

public function saltPass($salt, &$pass)
   // precondition: salt has been generated, password has been checked
   // postcondition: password is salted and ready for encryption
{
    return ($pass .= $salt);
}

public function insertUser ($name, $pass, $salt, email, $dbConn)
  // precondition: password has been salted and encrypted
  //              , email has been validated
  //              , username has been validated
  // postcondition: user info is inserted into DB
{
    // Store query in variable:
    $query = "INSERT INTO `userbase`(`user_name`, `user_pass` 
                                    ,`user_salt`, `user_email`)
              VALUES(:name, :pass 
                    ,:salt, :email)";

    // create new PDO (or MySQLi,etc) prepared statement:
    $pdo = $dbConn->prepare($query);
    //bind pdo named parameters:
    $pdo->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $pdo->bindParam(':pass', $pass, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $pdo->bindParam(':salt', $salt, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $pdo->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    // execute query:
    $pdo->execute();
    // get num of affected rows:
    $rows = $pdo->rowCount();

    return ($rows === 1) ? true : false;        
}
```

---

**Steps to Authorize:**

- Store user supplied user/pass (from login) in variables
- Retrieve password/salt from database
- Validate password against DB record
- Set session variable

---

### 3. Write Authorization Script:

```
public function getDbRecord($dbConn, $name, &$dbPass, &$dbSalt)
  // precondition: dbPass and dbSalt have been initialized
  // postcondition: dbPass and dbSalt contain db record
  //              , or are null if function returns false
{
    // create query:
    $query = "SELECT `user_pass` as 'pass', `user_salt` as 'salt'
              FROM `userbase`
              WHERE `user_name` = '". $dbConn->quote($name) ."'";

    // exec query and return rows:
    $pdo = $dbConn->query($query);
    // bind columns to dbPass and dbSalt
    $pdo->bindColumn('pass', $dbPass);
    $pdo->bindColumn('salt', $dbSalt);
    // fetch bound columns:
    $result = $pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND);

    if ($result === false)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

public function validateUser($pass, $dbSalt, $dbPass)
  // precondition: user exists and record retrieved via call to getDbRecord(...)
  // postcondition: user is either authorized or not via $_SESSION['auth']
  //              , function returns true or false depending on value of $_S['auth']
{
    // salt password with the same algorithm:
    $pass .= $dbSalt;

    // check password value:
    if (sha1($pass) === $dbPass) {
        $_SESSION['auth'] = TRUE;
        return true;
    } else {
        $_SESSION['auth'] = FALSE;
        return false;
    }
}
```

### Other Options:

You may be interested in looking into the **MCRYPT Package** which has native salting functionality.  Mcrypt does not come out of the box but rather is a part of the PHP Extension Community Library.  Mcrypt offers a number of hashing algorithms and a native salting mechanism.

More info on mcrypt can be found at: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php

Comment: Am I seeing correctly that you're never actually hashing the password before it goes into the database...?!

Comment: @deceze - I was showing how to salt the password, it is expected that the user will know how to encrypt it him/herself.

Comment: @deceze You obviously didn't read the pre-condition and post-condition  did you